# How can I get the current window handle number?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get the current window handle number (the 4), like this one:

```
driver.window_handles[4]
```

I'm already able to get the text using

```
driver.get_window_handle
```

But it gives me this string of text that I believe serves as an ID for the tab, right? Is there a simple way to get the number instead of this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code should work. It just loops through all the window handles, checks if each handle is the current window handle, then assigns the index of that handle to `current_window_handle_number`

```
tabs = driver.window_handles
for window_handle in tabs:
     if window_handle == driver.current_window_handle:
          tab = tabs.index(window_handle)
          print(tab)
```